# Ouput to be piped must be shared as 2 by 2 arguments

Tags: sed, pipe, stdout, xargs

How to share the piped output 2 by 2 arguments, only the first argument is for a printout command, i.e. echo to stdout/stderr, and the second argument for another command (let it be CMD), by making use of xargs

Ouput ie. the source to be piped can be as either the 2 arguments in one single line or 1 arg for 1 line, below all only illustration:

```
echo -e 'foo bar\nfoo1 bar1\nfoo2 bar2\n'  # ... much more
```

or

```
echo -e 'foo\nbar\nfoo1\nbar1\nfoo2\bar2\n'
```

so how is

```
echo -e 'foo bar\nfoo1 bar1\nfoo2 bar2\n' |xargs echo  |xargs CMD
```

supposed to be in real?
expected printout stdout/stderr result

```
foo
{output of CMD being fed with bar}

foo1
{output of CMD being fed with bar1}

foo2
{output of CMD being fed with bar2}

# ...
```

Comment: `( echo 1 2 3; echo  4; echo 5 6; ) | xargs -n 2 | while read a b; do echo "$a"; CMD "$b"; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xargs -n2` to do this by-2 args, then ab-use a shell scriptlet to handle `$1` and `$2` as e.g. (using `ls` as *CMD* just as example):

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\nfoo1\nbar1\nfoo2\nbar2'|xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo $1; ls $2' --
foo
ls: cannot access 'bar': No such file or directory
foo1
ls: cannot access 'bar1': No such file or directory
foo2
ls: cannot access 'bar2': No such file or directory
```

NOTE the needed `--` as last xargs argument